# Ternary Search:

Tags: python

I have written code for Ternary Search in Python. Need help to find out where I am going wrong.

Program should return the index of an element if the value is found in list else it should return -1
My code is not returning -1 when an element is not found. Also it works only when the input list is in the multiple of key.

```
-------------------------------
mylist=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25,27]
key=3


def ternary_search(mylist,key):
    l=0
    r=len(mylist)-1

    while l<=r:
        mid1= (l+r)//3
        mid2= (mid1+r)//2

        if mylist[mid1]==key or mylist[mid2]==key:
            if mylist[mid1]==key:
                return mid1

            else:
                return mid2

        elif mylist[l] < key and mylist[mid1] > key:
            r=mid1-1
        elif mylist[mid1] > key and mylist[mid2] < key:
            l=mid1+1
            r=mid2-1
        else:   
            l=mid2+1
    return -1


print(ternary_search(mylist,key))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate _in what way_ the program doesn't behave as expected, or if you have any indication where the error might occur.

Comment: Just play computer: you will see the failure in the first iteration.

Comment: The program is not finding last few elements also it should return -1 if an element is not found which it is not returning. Please help

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: start smaller, and run through your code by hand: take a piece of paper and a pencil, start with [3,5,7], and then start writing out what happens at each line of your code. This will only take a few minutes, but will almost certainly show you exactly what's going wrong, because you know what _should_ happen, and by running through each line, you're forced to double check that would should happen, actually happens. And if it works with 3 elements, add 1 more - now what happens?